# Quick-switching startup projects in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

In my application I often need to change the startup project from the UI shell to the tests and vice-versa.

I know that by using the context menu in Solution Explorer, I can right-click and select a project as the start-up project. However, there are many projects in my solution and this is time-consuming.

In VS 2010 I had macros to do this, but now they have been removed.

The question is: **In VS2012 is there a faster way to switch startup projects than finding them and using the right-click menu?** I will accept any answer (extensions, scripts etc)

Comment: I really want to know this too. Alternatively some way to set a "By Configuration" Startup project, So that the "Debug" configuration starts a Console application project, "Release" starts a Windows Service project and ideally "Test" runs the test suite though Gallio.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke - quick notification for you to check out the extension below :) worked well for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For that purpose I created the [VS extension SwitchStartupProject](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4e1be8c-b2dd-4dec-b273-dd88f8818571) that adds a toolbar dropdown box to switch the startup project.

Comment: Your extension is a godsend @Andreas - Where does it store the information set in the Options? I would like to be able to commit/share the different Multi-Project Startup Configurations to my team members.

Comment: @gakera The multi-project startup configurations and the other solution specific options are stored in a JSON file named `<YourSolutionName>.startup.suo` right next to your solution file.